# Wordpress h1 title on static home and h2 on other pages not working

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, title

I'm using this code with success on some wordpress installation, but with my new theme it doesn't work.

```
<?php echo is_home() ? '<h1>' : '<h2>'; ?>
 <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
    <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
 </a>
 <?php echo is_home() ? '</h1>' : '</h2>'; ?>
```

On this website I have a static page as front page which might be the reason of it not working.

I'm not so good with PHP so any help would be appreciated. I guess if i call the page name instead of home it might work but not sure about the syntax

Thanks!

Comment: Define `not working`. Condition is taking false every-time or true every-time ? Try to trace it

Comment: thanks. Not working means it is displaying h2 everytime now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing is_home() to is_front_page() , that should sort it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this code? What part isnt working? Is it the ternary operator not displaying h1/h2 or are the php functions not printing out the right information?

Comment: I'm trying to display h1 on homepage and h2 on other pages. But it displays h2 everywhere. Homepage is a static page set-up from the backend in Settings/Discussion tab.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't all page titles use H1? What do you put in the H1 on the "other pages"?

If you put the Website Title in there, you might reconsider doing that. Because a site title should not be H1. This is because Google sees all you pages having the same H1 tag which has a negative result on your page rank in Google.